# Angular2 routing feature module redirect to inner

Tags: angular

I have the following set-up (left out things for simplicity):

```
app/
  *app-routing.module
  *app.component
  *dashboard/
      *dashboard-routing.module
      *dashboard.component
      *dashboard-home/
          *dashboard-home.component
```

and the relevant code:

dashboard-routing:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes }   from '@angular/router';

// owned components
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { DashboardHomeComponent } from './dashboard-home/index';

// guards
import { AuthGuard } from '../core/index';

export const dashboardRoutedComponents = [DashboardComponent, DashboardHomeComponent];

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: DashboardHomeComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

app-routing:

```
import { NgModule }     from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// guards
import { AuthGuard } from './core/index';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

export const appRoutedComponents = [];
```

My problem is that when I navigate to `localhost:4200` it redirects me to `localhost:4200/dashboard`. If I then refresh the page it redirects me from `localhost:4200/dashboard` to `localhost:4200/dashboard/home`. Any idea how to make it jump directly to `localhost:4200/dashboard/home` from `localhost:4200` ??

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but not sure if correct way

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes }   from '@angular/router';

// owned components
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { DashboardHomeComponent } from './dashboard-home/index';

// guards
import { AuthGuard } from '../core/index';

export const dashboardRoutedComponents = [DashboardComponent, DashboardHomeComponent];

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: DashboardHomeComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```